# MS Teams desktop app changing session id between pages

Tags: php, cookies, progressive-web-apps, microsoft-teams, sessionid

I had a custom app in Microsoft Teams Desktop App that was working fine until this week when it stopped working.

The main issue is that it uses Cookies and a session id to keep track of temporary settings for given tasks.

Prior to this week the session ID, or at least cookies would remain persistent while switching tabs and while clicking the reload icon in the top right. I could press the refresh icon 20 times and the session id would not change, but now there is a new session id every time I reload.

The custom app is just a browser window that accesses our PWA app on a server.

Any one experiencing similar issues / is there a resolution for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: According to the updated SameSite restrictions, a browser doesn't add a cookie to an already authenticated web site if the link derives from an external site. You must ensure your authentication cookies are marked for cross site usage SameSite=None; Secure or ensure that a fallback is in place.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/samesite-cookie-update#authentication

Answer (score 0):

For exactly these kinds of reasons it's preferable not to use cookies in Teams apps. Even on the same machine, switching between Desktop and Web will give you issues, let alone switching devices. As an example, I use Teams on web, desktop and 2 mobile devices.

Instead, you can store state server-side (e.g. in a database or other store, keyed on the user's AadObject Id (their unique Azure Active Directory user guid), which is consistent in all places.